# How can i calculate to get centimeter for the second div width and height?

Tags: javascript, height, width

I have 2 div. First div is parent and second one is child.
For the first div, i have percentage and cm value for width and height.
for example ..

```
Width 47%  = Width 10 cm
Height 80%.  = Height 15 cm
```

For the second div, i have only percentage value of width and height,
for example ..

```
Width 60% = Width ? cm
Height 31% = Height ? cm
```

**How to calculate to get cm of width and height in javascript?**
Actual size is in cm but in web i have to calculate with percentage.

Comment: Please clarify, is the div styled with CSS? Are we talking about text inside the div? Ideally, create a [mre]. In general, if 47% = 10cm, then 60% = (10cm * 60) / 47

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, the div styled with Css. Second div is child of the First one. I think your answer (60% = (10cm * 60) / 47) will work. Thanks!